# Delphi XE4 IDE loading bpl very slow

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, bpl

Starting XE4 IDE usually takes a few seconds. Now I installed paxCompiler and loading paxComp_xe4.bpl takes about 40 sec. If I uninstall paxComp_xe4.bpl and load this bpl with code

```
LoadPackage('C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\11.0\bpl\paxcomp_xe4.bpl');
```

it takes only 0.3 sec.

Only IDE load this package very slow. Any idea what could be wrong. Unfortunately also the author of paxCompiler Alexander Baranovsky has no answer.
No problems with Delphi 2007.

**Edit**

If I run Delphi XE4 with a project that has no paxCompiler components then IDE is loaded immediately. But when I open project with paxCompiler components on the form it takes about 40 sec to load it completely. Because of this it is possible to conclude that creating components (in design-time) on the form is very slow ? But why? In the run-time everything is ok!

Comment: Profile what happens during load

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - how, what must I do

Comment: Time the load process to see where it is delayed

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Please look at what I added to the question.

Comment: You'll need to do some profiling/debugging to work out what is going on. If Baranovsky could not reproduce the problem then I guess you'll have to work out what is special about your environment.

Comment: 1) Close all in the IDE 2)How long does it take to open/load the project(group) in the IDE?

Comment: @BaoquanZuo - Small project with no paxCompiler components - 2 sec, with paxCompiler components - 40 sec.